# What is the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

我跑了3公里的步 vs 我跑步跑了3公里. They both mean "I ran for 3 km", right?

Comment: They have the same meaning with different kinds of syntaxes:1) I took a 3-kilometer race.  (S+V+O). 2) I ran 3 kilometers (S+V+Adv) in English. Now if you wanna know more about the difference in Chinese,please see TangHo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. 跑 | 3公里的 | 步

   - 跑步 is a simple (verb) + (noun) structure: 跑 (verb) + 步 (noun)
   - 3公里的 is a relative clause of the noun 步, that describe the length of it.
   - The relative clause 3公里的 is inserted between the verb and the noun 跑 | 3公里的 | 步
2. 跑步 | 跑了3公里 is a (topic) + (statement) structure

   - 跑步 (topic) + 跑了3公里 (statement)

The difference between #1. and #2. is:

1. treat 跑 | 步 as (verb) + (noun), then add a relative clause for the noun

The typical is :S+V+O.

2. 他（S）跑(V)步（O）跑了三公里（补语）。
   Notice that We can totally ignore “跑了三公里”, so this is just answering for "How long did he ran"？So that's 3 kilometers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, they both mean "I ran for 3km", but there does be difference between them, i will illustrate the difference in the aspect of what speaker want to emphasize rather than grammar matters.

"我跑了三公里的步": the main meaning speakers what to show is “我跑了步”-"I've run", no matter how long.

“我跑步跑了三公里”: the focus of this sentence is "我跑了三公里"-"I run for 3km".

In Chinese, the adjunct word ahead of a noun is not important at all, by contrast, the adjunct word after a noun does matter, because that's exactly what speakers want to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The second option uses an extra clause and reintroduces the main verb, the first uses 的 to separate verb 跑 from noun 步. You can generalize it:

我唱了三分钟的歌 vs. 我唱歌唱了三分钟.

Comment: Is there no difference in nuance or meaning? Both exactly the same?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference in meaning or nuance. Compare the same situation in english: I took a three hour walk / I took a walk for three hours / I took a walk, walked for three hours.

Comment: consult grammars about complements of quantity （数量补语），i.p. length (长度 e。g。 3公里）or duration (时量 e。g。３分钟）in case the verb (跑）has an object (步)（ 跑步 is a 离合词，but this does not change the form of the 2 possible constructions), they have come up at this site repeatedly, the last time with "Example cases with 了"

Answer (score 0):

> 我跑了3公里的步。

——I had a three-kilometer run.

> 我跑步跑了3公里。

——I ran 3 kilometers.

Both are right no matter you say these sentence in oral/formal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they have the same meaning.